# Build Configuration Error Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, configuration, build, devexpress

I'm trying to build my website project and publish it trough Visual Studio.Right now I see this error and can't figure out how to fix it. I see there is something wrong with devExpress versions ?Do i need to update it or something? Probably somebody already saw that kind of error and can help..
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i can suspect about your issue from  your provided details, there is some problem with your application Target framework and DevExpress dlls. Your application's Target Framework is 4.5 and as i can see from the last line in of the error log - **Version Information** - V4.0.xxx.

There may be two way to solve your problem as below:

- First try to degrade the application framework to 4.0 or upgrade the Web Application's pool Asp.net version to 4.5.
- Second clean the bin folder and Publish it again after Rebuild.

> If it does not solve your problem then please use recommendations from
>   the [KA18620: The "Could not load file or assembly 'X'" error message
>   appears](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/KA18620.aspx) KB Article to resolve this issue.
>
> **See Also:** [KA18663: Deployment Troubleshooting Guide](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/KA18663.aspx)

More references:
[Could not load file or assembly 'DevExpress.Web..."](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q572592)